# Variable for document being requested

Tags: nginx

If I have a location block that looks like this

```
location ~^ /foo/ { ... }
```

And I get a request to '/foo/bar', how do I just get 'bar'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
location ~ ^/foo/.*/?([^/]+)$
{
    set $doc $1;
    ...
}
```

The above assumes you want the very last part if the request, below the foo path.

If you just want the second part:

```
location ~ ^/foo/(.*)$
{
    set $doc $1;
}
```